# Что такое в консоли Chrome (Paused in debugger)?

Tags: google-chrome, консоль

Что это и как убрать. Заранее спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ссылка не рабочая

Comment: Вадим, а сейчас?

Comment: Breakpoint. Точка останова по русски. Вы либо её сами туда поставили, либо в коде написано `debugger`

Comment: @Nick как ее снять?

Comment: @Наташа, `ctrl+F8`

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть. Даже не знаю что сказать... Но  не думаю, что вопрос принесет пользу...

Comment: я так программировать начал, было дело зашел нечаянно в консоль F12, начал гуглить а нигде не написано что это такое, теперь вот работаю программистом

Comment: @PauloBerezini cool story

Answer (score 2):

**Paused in debugger** надпись обозначает, что у вас в коде или консоли стоит `Breakpoint`.

**Breakpoint** — это преднамеренное прерывание выполнения программы, при котором выполняется вызов отладчика(для того чтобы посмотреть, что выполняется в конкретном отрезке кода).

**Пример 1:** Когда вы сами нажали на клавиатуре кнопку F12 (O.S. Windows) и на вкладке мышкой отметили точку, для остановки выполнения скрипта:

[image: Пример 1]

**Пример 2:** Когда вы преднамеренно написали в коде `debugger;` перед куском кода, который вы бы хотели проверить

[image: Пример 2]

---

**В примере 1** вы можете отключить Breakpoint:

1. Нажав на номер строки мышкой.
2. Если вы хотите не учитывать все Breakpoint-ы, вы можете нажать Ctrl+F8 на клавиатуре(для повторного включения следует повторить операцию).

**В примере 2** вы можете:

1. Полностью отключить Breakpoint, изменив исходный код(удалить надпись `debugger;`).
2. Закоментировать его(что работает до первой перезагрузки страницы) `//debugger;`.